# Ive Been tTrying to run a code on ubuntu but i kepp getting the error message Could not find or load main class RecoverPassword

Tags: java, ubuntu, compiler-errors

Hey I am trying to run this program on a ubuntu command line
Ive tried

```
    javac RecoverPassword.java
```

It got compiled without any issues. but then i typed

```
    java RecoverPassword <argument> <argument>
```

I received the error.
Then i tried.

```
    java java.RecoverPassword <argument> <argument>
```

Still got the same error

NB. The code is written using eclipse.

Comment: In other worlds, if the class is in a package `my.stuff`, you have to call it as `java my.stuff.RecoverPassword a1 a2`.  You also need to set the class path or at least be at the beginning directory tree for the class file, `my/stuff/RecoverPassword.class`.

Comment: yes its in a package

Comment: still the same error